# How to RDP Ubuntu 16.04 and OSX from a Windows 10 Home Pc on lan

Tags: macos, windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, osx-lion

I've tryed to RDP an Ubuntu 16.04 and an Mac OSX-lion machine from a Windows Home Pc on a local lan without succsess. What steps should I take for such a connection and which programs, preferably open source are best to use? If there in a link to a tuturial, please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) is a proprietary protocol developed by Microsoft, it is not available on Linux. You can use third party software like VNC, Teamviewer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but i'd like to follow a native solution in lan, only, not Teamviewer or over internet

Comment: Try VNC on [ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04)